# How to use different content type in jemter.

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Scenario: I've two post requests in jmeter one is used for token generation which has content type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" and second is used for xyz operation by using that token has content type application/json, how can i perform this in jmeter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For 1st request just make sure to choose `POST` value from the "Method" dropdown and make sure that `Use multipart/form-data` box is **not** ticked

   [image: JMeter POST request]

   JMeter will automatically send `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request header for POST

   [image: JMeter Headers urlencoded]
2. For 2nd request add a [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) as a child and configure it to send the required [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header

   [image: JMeter Content Type]